# Utilizing an async RESTfull API in VB6

Tags: .net, vb6, vb6-migration

I've got a VB6 application that needs to talk to a RESTfull API with a async callback.

As VB6 doesn’t handle these async callbacks too well it's being planned to write the API calling part in .NET and reference the new .NET class in the VB6 application.

This is completely out of my hands but it just doesn’t sound right to me, as in callbacks on another thread being hosted by a VB6 application.

Would this work?  Or is there another way of doing this?

Comment: I have a production app using a similar architecture.  It has worked great for a long time.

Comment: was the .net code doing anything multi threaded or async ?

Comment: Yes.  The .net code was async, raising events to the VB6 front-end.

Comment: If your question is really about threading in the NET component you might want to change your question title. The RESTfull details seem to be secondary.

Answer (score -1):

It is possible and it is the best method. If you want to migrate from vb6 the best thing is to make new developments in .net and consume them using com interop.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/com-interop/

Comment: We have done a lot of migration already and in some situations we’re combing .net and vb6 very well.
I think my concerns are about the threading aspect. Can a .net class be multi-threaded when called from a vb6 application ?

Comment: @Karlsbergs Sorry for reopening this issue three years later but, I am currently in this same situation and I think I am having some issues making VB6 wait for the async callbacks. Did you find a solution by any chance? Thank you.